# Error: PasteSpecial method 2013

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy and paste the values form another workbook with the specific sheet named `Sheet1`. But when I run this code:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim conso as Worksheet
set conso = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With conso
        .Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        '.Paste
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
```

I got an error saying:

> PasteSpecial method of Worksheet class failed.

I'm trying to copy all the entire row of the `Sheet1` sheet to another workbook. Any help?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to paste the copied row? If you use WorkSheet.PasteSpecial in stead of Range.PasteSpecial it will paste to whatever is the activecell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try indicating where you need to paste the cells you copied:

```
With ActiveSheet.Rows(1)
    '.Paste
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```